# left bar is not showing any content in it just showing the place of

Tags: layout, magento-1, catalog, layered-navigation

Here is my **local.xml** file code:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
</catalog_category_layered>
<tag_product_list>
    <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
            <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>../../</link></crumbInfo>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
        <crumbName>Tags</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo><label>Tags</label><title>Tags</title><link></link></crumbInfo>
        </action>
    </reference>
</tag_product_list>
```

and it is sourcing the left bar from **frontend/mgstheme/default/template/mgs/mpanel/template/layout/category/left.phtml** But i have active theme frontend/mgstheme/luxury/.....

And this is my **local.xml** file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQ1WRjkUEDudHhDel9Va0J4OGc/view?usp=sharing

Also see the attached screenshot, it is not showing any thing in left bar. i need to add layered navigation in left section.

[image]
Please advice.

Comment: Have you tried setting `Is Anchor` to false in the admin Category page?

Comment: yes i tried but not luck..

Comment: Here is the link to my page:
http://mxcounters.com/usa-tiles/index.php/mosaics/glass-mosaics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are main issue related to that.

> Category is anchor
>
> Product have attribute
>
> attribute must be dropdown
>
> reindexing needed after creating the attribute

**Make sure you check all these options.**

Comment: Getting this error: 
Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in

Answer (score 1):

first of all you are not mentioning if you are in a category page, or a product page? so first you need to tell us what page is it?? because they are going to have different handlers, I assume based on your code you have a category page and you want to show the left side bar there. second, I do not see the phtml file you are mentioning in any section of your code, so again I assume you want category/left.phtml ,

You are referencing it to the root which is wrong, you should reference it to the left, you have structural blocks which has left and right and content so do this:

```
 <reference name="left">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>category/left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Comment: I am at category page... there is a main category and then it has a sub category.as follows

site_url/parent_category/child category

Comment: Under which handle  i have to put this code? can you please check the updated question with local.xml file.